# What do minute rates of Timer and Meter metrics indicate?

Tags: java, metrics, yammer

We are trying to achieve reporting functionality based on information from Yammer metrics.

Yammer metrics provides information about Timers and Meters as shown below:

```
METER_METRIC:
             count = 1
         mean rate = 0.01 count/s
     1-minute rate = 0.00 count/s
     5-minute rate = 0.00 count/s
    15-minute rate = 0.00 count/s

TIMER_METRIC:
             count = 1
         mean rate = 0.01 calls/s
     1-minute rate = 0.01 calls/s
     5-minute rate = 0.00 calls/s
    15-minute rate = 0.00 calls/s
               min = 89.77ms
               max = 89.77ms
              mean = 89.77ms
            stddev = 0.00ms
            median = 89.77ms
              75% <= 89.77ms
              95% <= 89.77ms
              98% <= 89.77ms
              99% <= 89.77ms
            99.9% <= 89.77ms
```

I read [an overview](https://web.archive.org/web/20150205091657/http://engineering.snapdeal.com/2014/06/yammer-metrics-monitoring-your_12.html) and am able to get the application statistics as shown above. The Timer and Meter metrics have information about the 1-minute rate, 5-minute rate and 15-minute rate.

**Question:**

What do the minute rates of the Timer and Meter metrics indicate and how those are getting calculated?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

All `(mean|1-min|5-minute|15-minute)-rate` metrics indicate **throughput**; i.e., how many units of information (events) where processed per second.

**Mean rate**

Calculates the rate at which events have occurred since the meter was created. But that's not very useful because it doesn't represent what is happening *right now*.

**Minute rates**

Calculates the rate at which events have ocurred using a technique called *Exponentially-weighted moving average (EWMA)*.

This rate has the same exponential decay factor as the fifteen-minute load average in the `top` Unix command.

**More Information**

Take a look at the source code of [Timer.java](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/4.0-maintenance/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/Timer.java),  [Meter.java](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/4.0-maintenance/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/Meter.java) and [EWMA.java](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/4.0-maintenance/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/EWMA.java)

If you have more time, take a look at a talk about the topic by Coda Hale: [Metrics, Metrics, Everywhere - Coda Hale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czes-oa0yik)

Answer (score 0):

It indicates an average request rate in a given time period. While mean rate is average for timer's lifetime.